# How to Disable Visual Studio Code from Auto-Launching?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

When I type the name of a python script in MS Command Prompt, my Visual Studio Code program automatically launches and it prevents the python script from running in Command Prompt where I want it to run.  How can I prevent it from launching please?  I have Python 3.10.1 installed and VS Code 1.65.2.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you typing `python [script].py`, or just `[script].py`?

did you set vscode to be the default application to launch .py files? Check your default programs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs-in-windows-e5d82cad-17d1-c53b-3505-f10a32e1894d

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm typing just [path]\[script].py.  I did not recently set VSCode to be the default application to launch .py files.  However, I've had it installed for many months and this issue just began after I opened VSCode for the first time in many months.  Perhaps it ran some update.  Thanks!